# Translate pipe not working in angular material dialog

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-translate

I'm quite new in Angular. I looked for answers in doc and stackoverflow but I haven't found it. So, sorry if my question is obvius.

I created a component to hold my modal content in a separated file. I open this modal using open.dialog like this from parent component:

```
  openMyModalDialog() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(MyModalComponent, {
      panelClass: 'own-modal',
      width: '300px'
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      alert('closed');
    });
  }
```

Well, MyModalComponent:

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>{{ 'myTargetTranslateKey' | translate }}</h1>
<div mat-dialog-content>
  <p>What's your favorite animal?</p>
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Favorite Animal</mat-label>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button (click)="onNoClick()">No Thanks</button>
</div>
```

I don't import TranslateModule in the modal component, because I think that's imported in the module.

```
...

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    TranslateModule,
    MomentModule,
    IMaskModule,
```

It's also imported in `app.module.ts`. using TranslateModule.forRoot().

**It's important to say that | translate pipe works in any other components / code, also in the parent which opens the dialog**.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**: I've imported TranslateService from ngx-translate/core in the modal component. I put a console.log on close event, and I can see that this.translateSevice.instant('key') works!... So the problem is the pipe doesn't work.

**UPDATE 2**: It also works with `<h1 mat-dialog-title [translate]="'key'"></h1>` but it doesn't with the pipe! :'(

**UPDATE 3**: Pipe doesn't work means that the result is empty, nothing is displayed but there aren't errors in the console neither.

Comment: Hi @dmanso, what do you mean by "not working" - text is not being translated, or you get an error `the pipe 'translate' could not be found`?

Comment: @AntonTemchenko sorry, I'm gonna edit the question right now. The result is empty, but no errors are displayed in the console, neither `'translate' could not be found` from which I've been reading.

Maybe, another clue, I'm having also problems (I work with Material Angular) injecting data to a dialog. I can't see in the template, but I see the data injected if I console.log.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. Sorry for this novice error.

The example I've copied from angular-material doc has an inner component (mat-form-...) which is not imported and I don't use.

No error messages, nothing. I remove it and everything works fine.

Thanks.